# Publish docker images to AWS ECR from Jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, amazon-ecr

Following this discussion- [Integrate Amazon Elastic Container Registry with Jenkins](https://serverfault.com/questions/744902/integrate-amazon-elastic-container-registry-with-jenkins#new-answer?newreg=9fccd8d337444d31b9b70e607f82e3e4),

After publishing my image to ECR  from Jenkins using a shell script, it works- but  another image with empty tag is published each time (with different Digest). Trying to recreate this I created another Repository in the ECR and when the image was published from my local cmd (using the same script) in the new Repository it didn't happen.

Did anyone encountered something similar, or has a suggestion regarding what could cause it?

Answer (score 0):

I think it happened because you push the updated image with the same tag (suppose you use imagename:latest)
When you push for the first time - you get only one image in your repository and it has a tag "latest".
When you try to push updated image with the same "latest" tag, in  ECR the same tag cannot be on two different images, so it is put on a new image, but removed from the previously "latest" image, thus leaving it without any tags. 
So the image that you see with "empty tag" is just a previous version of your image.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm pushing the images with different tags- the tag is an increasing integer in every push. Maybe it can be caused because of a common base-image?